# ASP.NET MVC login popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET, I'm working on a project with ASP.NET MVC with a database-first approach to both UI and API-separate solutions. I am trying to run the UI solution and noticed that login pop-up, but I didn't see where it came from if I wanted to pop-up because I didn't see any login page in the UI solution, but I saw the authorization and OAuthResponse codes. I added a screenshot of what it looks like.

Could anyone please help me on this one?

[Screenshot of the login pop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7OuH.png)

In the API solution, we have the authentication and authorization logic. It works, but what I try to do is give access to a specific user; they don't need to enter their credentials. I tried adding the list of users and giving them access, but it didn't work, so now I'm trying to create only a copy of the old UI with the same API and database. With these new copy UIs, I'm trying to remove the login authentication and authorization parts from the UI and directly point them to the index page.

Comment: Looks like a prompt for HTTP Basic authentication.  Is that what your app is using?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a simplified version of your UI where certain users can access the application without the need for authentication. If I understand correctly, you want to bypass the login authentication and authorization for specific users in this new copy of the UI.

Comment: Yes, Vishvadeep sing, I am trying to bypass the login authentication and authorization for specific users in this new copy of the UI.